# How to call function which add span to input, radio button in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop

Prestashop 1.6 has some strange functions. One of them is:

```
\themes\my_theme\js\autoload\15-jquery.uniform-modified.js
```

Which add span to radio, input button. For example:

```
<div class="checker" id="uniform-cgv">
  <span class="checked">
    <input name="cgv" id="cgv" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </span>
</div>
```

If this span has class checked then checkbox is checked. the problem is when quest user want buy products without create a account. The user need to provide some information about his self. In the end click on "save" button

```
<button type="submit" name="submitGuestAccount" id="submitGuestAccount" class="btn btn-default button button-medium"><span>Zapisz<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span></button>
```

When I click this button the html is change to:

```
<p class="checkbox">
     <input name="cgv" id="cgv" value="1" checked="checked" type="checkbox">
</p>
```

the question is. How can I call function which add span to input field after click on this button. For now I have something like this:

```
$('#submitGuestAccount').click(function () {

});
```

Below I past all content from:
[view-source:https://dev.suszek.info/themes/default-bootstrap/js/autoload/15-jquery.uniform-modified.js](https://dev.suszek.info/themes/default-bootstrap/js/autoload/15-jquery.uniform-modified.js)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the same checkbox like with uniform you just need to invoke method bindUniform() after your button was handled. I assume that you get an answer after form handling with an ajax response, so you need to add

`if (typeof bindUniform !=='undefined') {
    bindUniform();
}`

after you get response and DOM was done.

Comment: I don't understand everything what You said. But your code, helped me to find this: $("select.form-control,input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").uniform(); and after post this uniform fixed my checkbox. Thanks for your time. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander Grosul Thanks again. To fix this issues You need to add this code to  any js file.

```
$("select.form-control,input[type='radio'],input[type='checkbox']").uniform();
```